# Theorem 2.14 (The dual of $L^p(\Omega)$) in Lieb's Analysis book

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

The following pictures are [Theorem 2.14 (The dual of $L^p(\Omega)$](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=Eb_7oRorXJgC&pg=PA61&dq=2.14+Theorem+The+dual+of&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2ntrh8erMAhWELaYKHWYhDyoQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=2.14%20Theorem%20The%20dual%20of&f=false) in Lieb's Analysis book and its proof of the case $1<p<\infty$.

My question is how to get the inequility (3) in the red box? It really makes me wonder...

**Edit:** Add the picture of Lemma 2.8 at the bottom.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you check what lemma 2.8 in the book says?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Sorry I forgot, I have added the picture of Lemma 2.8 at the very bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've missed something, the authors made a little mistake there, but the result is of course true. Lemma 2.18 states that there exists $h\in K$ such that 
$$
\operatorname{Re}\int (k-h)u \leq 0
$$
for all $k\in K$. This can be rewritten into
$$
\operatorname{Re}\int ku \leq \operatorname{Re}\int hu
$$
for all $k\in K$. Not having $0$ on the right hand side is actually not a problem here, because $K$ is indeed a complex linear space, and thus
$$
\lambda\operatorname{Re}\int ku \leq \operatorname{Re}\int hu\quad\text{and}\quad  \lambda\operatorname{Im}\int ku \leq \operatorname{Re}\int hu
$$
for all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, thus $\int ku=0$.

I checked their [errata](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~loss/other/2ndedition/errata150404.pdf), but this does not seem to be in there. If you feel like this is important, and you're confident it is a mistake, you can send them an email about it.

Comment: Nice, the key is that $K$ is a complex linear space. Thanks!